# Updating object attributes from within module run in multiprocessor process

Tags: python, module, multiprocessing

I am relatively new to python and definitely new to multiprocessing. I'm following [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802368/how-to-start-multiple-jobs-in-python-and-communicate-with-the-main-job) for the structure of my multiprocessing, but in `def func_A`, I'm calling a module that passes a class object as one of the arguments. In the module, I change an object attribute that I would like the main program to see and update the user with the object attribute value. The child processes run for very long times, so I need the main program to provide updates as they run.

My suspicion is that I'm not understanding namespace/object scoping or something similar, but from what I've read, passing an object (an instance of a class?) to a module as an argument passes a reference to the object and not a copy. I would have thought this meant that changing the attributes of the object in the child process/module would have changed the attributes in the main program object (since they're the same object). Or am I confusing things?

The code for my main program:

```
# MainProgram.py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from time import sleep
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import myModule

MYOBJECTNAMES = ['name1','name2']

class myClass:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.value = 0

myObjects = []
for n in MYOBJECTNAMES:
  myObjects.append(myClass(n))

def func_A(process_number, queue):
  start = datetime.now()
  print("Process {} (object: {}) started at {}".format(process_number, myObjects[process_number].name, start))
  myModule.Eval(myObjects[process_number])
  sys.stdout.flush()

def multiproc_master():
  queue = mp.Queue()
  proceed = mp.Event()

  processes = [mp.Process(target=func_A, args=(x, queue)) for x in range(len(myObjects))]
  for p in processes:
    p.start() 

  for i in range(100):
    for o in myObjects:
      print("In main: Value of {} is {}".format(o.name, o.value))
    sleep(10)

  for p in processes:  
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  split_jobs = multiproc_master()
  print(split_jobs)
```

The code for my module program:

```
# myModule.py
from time import sleep

def Eval(myObject):

  for i in range(100):
    myObject.value += 1
    print("In module: Value of {} is {}".format(myObject.name, myObject.value))
    sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802368/how-to-start-multiple-jobs-in-python-and-communicate-with-the-main-job) you linked to probably was probably a poor choice to use as a template, as it's doing many things that your code doesn't require (much less use).

I think your biggest misconception about how multiprocessing works is thinking that all the code is running in the same address-space. The main task runs in its own, and there are separate ones for each subtask. The way your code is written, **each** of them will end up with its own separate `myObjects` list. That's why the main task doesn't see any of the changes made by any of the other tasks.

While there *are* ways share objects using the `multiprocessing` module, doing so often introduces significant overhead because keeping it or them all in-sync between all the processes requires lots of things happening "under the covers" to make *seem* like they're shared (which is what is really going on since they can't actually be because of having separate address-spaces). This overhead frequently completely cancels out any speed gained by parallel-processing.

As stated in the documentation: "[*when doing concurrent programming it is usually best to avoid using shared state as far as possible*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)".

Comment: Thanks @martineau... the different address space makes sense and good to know. Maybe you know, but do you think a better approach would be for each module or subprocess to update a database and the main program pull information from that?

Comment: @physicsnerd: Storing the objects in a database sounds like a feasible approach since (generally) they support concurrent access to their contents.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.