# How can I run a script on when I call a process.join?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a few processes that are meant to run in a while loop. I basically have some processes collecting data, and before they stop, I want them to save the data to a csv or json file. What I have right now is using the super function to override the join method in the multiprocessing.Process class.

```
class Processor(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, arguments):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.main_function()

    def main_function(self):
        While True:
            #do things to incoming data

    def function_on_join(self):
        #do one last thing before the process ends

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        self.function_on_join()
        super(Processor, self).join(timeout=timeout)
```

Is there a better way/correct way/more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you'll take a look at [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module.

if you can describe your job as list of tasks to be done by a pool of workers.

## Task Based multiprocessing

when you have a sequence of `jobs` (e.g. list of filenames) and you want them to be processed in parallel - you can do so as follows:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor    
import requests

def get_url(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    print(f'{url} - {resp.status_code}')
    return url

jobs = ['http://google.com', 'http://python.org', 'http://facebook.com']

# create process pool of 3 workers
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as pool:
    # run in parallel each job and gather the returned values
    return_values = list(pool.map(get_url, jobs))

print(return_values)
```

outputs:

```
http://google.com - 200
http://python.org - 200
http://facebook.com - 200
['http://google.com', 'http://python.org', 'http://facebook.com']
```

## Not Task-Based Multiprocessing

When you just want to run multiple subprocesses that not consuming jobs like the first case, you may want to use [`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class).

you can use it similarly to [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) in a procedural fashion as well as OOP fashion.

**Example for procedural fashion** (IMHO more pythonic):

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

def func():
    print(f'hello from: {os.getpid()}')

processes = [Process(target=func) for _ in range(4)]  # creates 4 processes

for process in processes:
    process.daemon = True  # close the subprocess if the main program closes
    process.start()  # start the process
```

outputs:

```
hello from: 31821
hello from: 31822
hello from: 31823
hello from: 31824
```

## Waiting for Processes to Finish

if you want to wait using `Process.join()` (more info on `process.join()` & `process.daemon` on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25391156/7438048)) you can do it like this:

```
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def func():
    time.sleep(3)
    print(f'hello from: {os.getpid()}')

processes = [Process(target=func) for _ in range(4)]  # creates 4 processes

for process in processes:
    process.start()  # start the process

for process in processes:
    process.join()  # wait for the process to finish

print('all processes are done!')
```

this outputs:

```
hello from: 31980
hello from: 31983
hello from: 31981
hello from: 31982
all processes are done!
```