Process.Join() is delayed?
It appears Process.Join() waits for something to happen before continuing?
I have multiple scrapers running in different processes. Here is one of them:
    def scraper_1(urls, start_time, ret_list, profile):
        sb = Driver(uc=True, user_data_dir=profile, headless2=True)

        card_dict = {}
        for url in urls:

            sb.default_get(url[1])
            # functional code that fills card_dict

        sb.quit()
        ret_list.append(card_dict)
        print(f'###########    SCRAPER 1 FINISHED       ########### {"{:.2f}".format(time() - start_time)}')

In my scrape() function, I define all scraping processes and 'track' them:
    def scrape(start_time):
        print(f'###########    STARTED  SCRAPING    ########### {"{:.2f}".format(time() - start_time)}')

        manager = Manager()
        ret_list = manager.list()

        path1 = os.path.abspath("./profiles")

        p_scraper1 = Process(target=scraper_1, args=(urls1, start_time, ret_list, path1))

        p_scraper1.start()

        p_scraper1.join()
        print(f'scraper 1 joined {"{:.2f}".format(time() - start_time)}')

I'd expect the messages "Scraper 1 finished" and "Scraper 1 joined" to be almost simultaneously, but there's an almost 10-second delay between them. Is this something I should expect, or is there something I'm overlooking?

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25391025/150978 (assuming there was no change from Python2 to python3)

@Robert the way I interpreted that post is to make sure the main process is finished but the children are still running. In my case, the main process is waiting for the children to finish so it can continue. Did I not understand the answer correctly?

Can you make a smaller reproduce of the problem without the Driver related logic?
